Free platforms for multi-agent reinforcement learning algorithms?
I am looking for free platforms which include  multi-agent reinforcement learning algorithms such as Q-RTS, MAPPO, QMIX and FACMAC. Any suggestion?

I think you will need to give more details on what you are trying to do, and which aspects you expect to be free. Also which aspects you expect to be provided by the platform. For example you could probably set up a Google Colab to run the algorithm, and use that to get some free compute. But it's not an all-in-one solution, you would need to find an open source implementation of the algorithm and combine with your environment in a Jupyter script
